# Is there a missing word at this headline?

Tags: vocabulary, american-english, learning

The headline is:

'For a parent this anxious delta fall, the only way out is through'

i missing word can couse big trouble for someone learining English, would that sentence be something like:

'For a parent on this anxious delta fall, the only way out is through'

add the 'on' made sense to me

Comment: Headlines are always tough, but no, I don't think there is any word missing here.  "this fall" means "during this autumn".  We say that something happens *this fall* (or this week, or this year, or this July, etc.), not *on* this fall.

Answer (score 1):

There is no missing word. We can talk about seasons of the year without using a preposition:

It was cold last winter

It may be warm next summer

The leaves on the trees are pretty this fall ('fall' is what Americans call autumn).

This 'anxious delta fall' is the fall of 2021, during which parents are anxious about their children because of the Delta variant of the Coronavirus Covid-19.

Sometimes we use 'in', but never 'on' for seasons.

It is cold in the winter in Norway.